# Reduce duplication of model across DB, backend, and frontend

Tags: mysql, reactjs, flask, model

I am building a web app using flask (no ORM) backed by a MySQL DB, and React on the frontend. I have a concern in that my model is duplicated in both MySQL, Flask, and React. As an example, say I have the following MySQL table

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE pet (name VARCHAR(20), owner VARCHAR(20),
-> species VARCHAR(20), sex CHAR(1), birth DATE, death DATE);
```

Then in the flask app, let's say I wanted to insert into `pet`. Then the flask view would expect a body with the following fields `name`, `owner`, `species`, `sex`, `birth`, and `death`, and it would also have to know to insert into a schema with fields of those names. So you would need something like `body = request.get_json()`and then `'INSERT INTO pet (name, owner, ...) VALUES ({name}, {owner}, ...)'.format(**body)`

On the frontend, we would have to maintain a state similar to the backend, like

```
this.state = {
  name: ...,
  owner: ...,
  ...
}
```

if let's say these values were coming from a form. And then we would have to POST these values by sending a body like this

```
{
  name: this.state.name,
  owner: this.state.owner,
  ...
}
```

In addition to duplication, it seems it is error-prone, as what if the frontend accidentally sent `ownerName` instead of `owner`? then the backend tries to parse the body with a field named `owner` but it doesn't find anything.

Let's say instead that the backend was returning data to the frontend, such as executing `SELECT name, owner FROM pet`. Then the backend serializes the response into JSON and the frontend has to parse it. The frontend would then need to expect objects with properties called `name` and `owner`. If it instead expected i.e `petName` then this would be a bug.

In summary, the model is duplicated

- in the DB Table
- in the backend logic when querying the DB
- in the backend logic when parsing the body of a post request
- in the frontend state
- in the frontend when sending a request body
- in the frontend when rendering a response from the backend

Certainly this issue has been faced by others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the model/backend code in your front end code you need to use some framework like [Uninode](https://github.com/tuoitrevohoc/UniNode) which use the same programming language (TypeScript) on both backend and frontend.

Comment: Can you please expound upon your answer? How would this help maintain and reduce duplication of the model across the stack?

Comment: You declare the model Pet.ts once. And then it is used to generate the data schema, query to get data, return as json to the frontend and display in react.